# How can I determine type and size of common image types in Python?

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I'm working on a set of libraries for processing Microsoft Office Open XML documents. In the course of embedding pictures in Word and PowerPoint documents, I need to determine the MIME type of the image and a few header details like pixel dimensions, dpi would be nice too.

Currently I'm using Pillow to do this, but as dependencies go it's less than ideal. I only use a couple statements against the library, but the dependency requires that folks have a C compiler and image libraries like libjpeg installed. This makes the install especially challenging on Windows, although even on OS X it more involved than I'd like.

Is there a way that I can get just the basics with a pure Python imaging library or perhaps just merge a reasonably simple module with my distribution?

Comment: If the distribution of extension modules is the problem, you can create wheels containing pre-built binaries.

Comment: There are windows binaries available for Pillow on pypi: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, using Pillow is probably best solution, especially since you can [download windows binaries from pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.2.1).

A quick google search resulted in [this pure-python function](http://evaisse.tumblr.com/post/17551554979/get-image-size-info-using-pure-python-code) to get the size of GIF, PNG and JPEG images:

```
import struct
from cStringIO import StringIO


def get_image_info(data):
    """
    Return (content_type, width, height) for a given img file content
    no requirements
    """
    data = str(data)
    size = len(data)
    height = -1
    width = -1
    content_type = ''

    # handle GIFs
    if (size >= 10) and data[:6] in ('GIF87a', 'GIF89a'):
        # Check to see if content_type is correct
        content_type = 'image/gif'
        w, h = struct.unpack("<HH", data[6:10])
        width = int(w)
        height = int(h)

    # See PNG 2. Edition spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/)
    # Bytes 0-7 are below, 4-byte chunk length, then 'IHDR'
    # and finally the 4-byte width, height
    elif ((size >= 24) and data.startswith('\211PNG\r\n\032\n')
          and (data[12:16] == 'IHDR')):
        content_type = 'image/png'
        w, h = struct.unpack(">LL", data[16:24])
        width = int(w)
        height = int(h)

    # Maybe this is for an older PNG version.
    elif (size >= 16) and data.startswith('\211PNG\r\n\032\n'):
        # Check to see if we have the right content type
        content_type = 'image/png'
        w, h = struct.unpack(">LL", data[8:16])
        width = int(w)
        height = int(h)

    # handle JPEGs
    elif (size >= 2) and data.startswith('\377\330'):
        content_type = 'image/jpeg'
        jpeg = StringIO(data)
        jpeg.read(2)
        b = jpeg.read(1)
        try:
            while (b and ord(b) != 0xDA):
                while (ord(b) != 0xFF): b = jpeg.read
                while (ord(b) == 0xFF): b = jpeg.read(1)
                if (ord(b) >= 0xC0 and ord(b) <= 0xC3):
                    jpeg.read(3)
                    h, w = struct.unpack(">HH", jpeg.read(4))
                    break
                else:
                    jpeg.read(int(struct.unpack(">H", jpeg.read(2))[0])-2)
                b = jpeg.read(1)
            width = int(w)
            height = int(h)
        except struct.error:
            pass
        except ValueError:
            pass

    return content_type, width, height
```

Note that the code on that blog was written by *Emmanuel VAÏSSE*. There is no license specified on his blog so depending on where you want to include the code you *might* want to re-implement the function or ask him to be onthe safe site.

Comment: Sweet! this is very encouraging that implementing just the bits I need right in the package might be very feasible, thanks for this! I'll have a study on this to see what he's doing and do some searching to find out more about the headers etc. :)